# reupload package to launchpad with orig.tar.gz changed

Tags: packaging, launchpad, deb

I uploaded a package geos-3.3.8.orig.tar.gz to launchpad with success, but the build failed because a mistake in the source code, then I have changed my geos-3.3.8.orig.tar.gz with the right code, and ran debuild -S again, but now I get an email with rejected warning because dsc file is not correct (checksums have changed)

How can I reupload again the package?

Answer (score 1):

You do NOT change the origional source code, you submit a patch. If it is to the source code, the patch should almost certainly go upstream.

See - http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug.html

If you are packaging for Ubuntu I HIGHLY suggest you read the packaging guidelines.

See either the Debian or Ubuntu documentation, this is a "quick start"

http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages

http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/packaging-new-software.html

Comment: I did a big mistake in the source, and its my fault, I mean I don't want to create a patch to solve my previous error, its better to delete and start again?

Comment: Then in launchapd, every time I fail to build a package, I have to bump de version?

Comment: Are you the upstream maintainer ? The best solution is likely to fix the source code and bump the version , ie from 1.0 to 1.1 or some such.